# Converting JavaScript RSA Function into a PHP one

Tags: php, javascript, html, rsa, phpseclib

I've got a Problem with converting a JS-based RSA File into PHP.

JavaScript:

Main File:

```
var RSAPublicKey = function($modulus_hex, $encryptionExponent_hex) {
   this.modulus = new BigInteger( $modulus_hex, 16);
   this.encryptionExponent = new BigInteger( $encryptionExponent_hex, 16);
}

var Base64 = {
base64: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
encode: function($input) {
    if (!$input) {
        return false;
    }
    var $output = "";
    var $chr1, $chr2, $chr3;
    var $enc1, $enc2, $enc3, $enc4;
    var $i = 0;
    do {
        $chr1 = $input.charCodeAt($i++);
        $chr2 = $input.charCodeAt($i++);
        $chr3 = $input.charCodeAt($i++);
        $enc1 = $chr1 >> 2;
        $enc2 = (($chr1 & 3) << 4) | ($chr2 >> 4);
        $enc3 = (($chr2 & 15) << 2) | ($chr3 >> 6);
        $enc4 = $chr3 & 63;
        if (isNaN($chr2)) $enc3 = $enc4 = 64;
        else if (isNaN($chr3)) $enc4 = 64;
        $output += this.base64.charAt($enc1) + this.base64.charAt($enc2) + this.base64.charAt($enc3) + this.base64.charAt($enc4);
    } while ($i < $input.length);
    return $output;
},
decode: function($input) {
    if(!$input) return false;
    $input = $input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
    var $output = "";
    var $enc1, $enc2, $enc3, $enc4;
    var $i = 0;
    do {
        $enc1 = this.base64.indexOf($input.charAt($i++));
        $enc2 = this.base64.indexOf($input.charAt($i++));
        $enc3 = this.base64.indexOf($input.charAt($i++));
        $enc4 = this.base64.indexOf($input.charAt($i++));
        $output += String.fromCharCode(($enc1 << 2) | ($enc2 >> 4));
        if ($enc3 != 64) $output += String.fromCharCode((($enc2 & 15) << 4) | ($enc3 >> 2));
        if ($enc4 != 64) $output += String.fromCharCode((($enc3 & 3) << 6) | $enc4);
    } while ($i < $input.length);
    return $output; 
}
};

var Hex = {
hex: "0123456789abcdef",
encode: function($input) {
    if(!$input) return false;
    var $output = "";
    var $k;
    var $i = 0;
    do {
        $k = $input.charCodeAt($i++);
        $output += this.hex.charAt(($k >> 4) &0xf) + this.hex.charAt($k & 0xf);
    } while ($i < $input.length);
    return $output;
},
decode: function($input) {
    if(!$input) return false;
    $input = $input.replace(/[^0-9abcdef]/g, "");
    var $output = "";
    var $i = 0;
    do {
        $output += String.fromCharCode(((this.hex.indexOf($input.charAt($i++)) << 4) & 0xf0) | (this.hex.indexOf($input.charAt($i++)) & 0xf));
    } while ($i < $input.length);
    return $output;
}
};

var RSA = {

getPublicKey: function( $modulus_hex, $exponent_hex ) {
    return new RSAPublicKey( $modulus_hex, $exponent_hex );
},

encrypt: function($data, $pubkey) {
    if (!$pubkey) return false;
    $data = this.pkcs1pad2($data,($pubkey.modulus.bitLength()+7)>>3);
    if(!$data) return false;
    $data = $data.modPowInt($pubkey.encryptionExponent, $pubkey.modulus);
    if(!$data) return false;
    $data = $data.toString(16);
    return Base64.encode(Hex.decode($data));
},

pkcs1pad2: function($data, $keysize) {
    if($keysize < $data.length + 11)
        return null;
    var $buffer = [];
    var $i = $data.length - 1;
    while($i >= 0 && $keysize > 0)
        $buffer[--$keysize] = $data.charCodeAt($i--);
    $buffer[--$keysize] = 0;
    while($keysize > 2)
        $buffer[--$keysize] = Math.floor(Math.random()*254) + 1;
    $buffer[--$keysize] = 2;
    $buffer[--$keysize] = 0;
    return new BigInteger($buffer);
}
}
```

How I use it:

```
var pubKey = RSA.getPublicKey( results.publickey_mod, results.publickey_exp );
var encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt( form.elements['password'].value, pubKey );
```

Now I want to convert this into PHP, thing I have tried so far:

```
$pkey = $json["publickey_mod"];
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$rsa->loadKey($pkey);
$rsa->exponent = $json["publickey_exp"];
echo ($rsa->setPublicKey($pkey))?"success":"fail";

$plain = "text";
echo $rsa->encrypt($plain);
```

But it always prints a "fail", what's wrong with it?

How the Key looks like:

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

Comment: have you tried `->exponent = pack('H*', 'CD5D....');` instead?

Comment: Exponent has got a different Format, it's a Linux Timestamp

Comment: I meant, use `$pkey = pack('H*', $json['publickey_mod']);`

Comment: Tried it, still giving me a fail (and a false)...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old lol but it looks like you're using PKCS#1 padding. phpseclib uses OAEP padding by default. Try doing this:

```
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
```